# Zend setBaseUrl() difference?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller

Simple question, just no luck on Google.
I was wondering it there  is a difference in using

`Zend_Controller_Request_Http::setBaseUrl();` and `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::setBaseUrl('');`

It seemed to me that using `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::setBaseUrl('')` could be seen as accident prone later on, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result is the same. Rather than worrying about which one to use, just don't set a base URL if you don't have one.